# How can I Handle Rainbow Cursor at Event

Tags: macos

I want to write a troubleshooting apps with macOS. And, I could find how to catch user occurred events like mouse or trackpad tap with CGEventType: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgeventtype

But, I need to handle the rainbow cursor at my code. How can I do this in Objective C or Swift code?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean by "handle"?

Comment: @PhillipMills I want to kick my method when the rainbow cursor started and ended, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29995997